# Почему функция возвращает None в Python?

Tags: python, функции

Мне нужно было решить задачу - Даны три числа. Найдите те два из них, сумма которых наибольшая.
Вроде бы правильно её решил, но код возвращает в место двух максимальных чисел None.

Код:

```
a = int(input('Введите первое число: '))
b = int(input('Введите второе число: '))
c = int(input('Введите третье число: '))

def maximum(a, b, c):
    if a > b:
        if a > c:
            if c > b:
                return "Два максимальных элемента: " + str(a) + ", " + str(c)

print(maximum(a, b, c))
```

Помогите плз)

Comment: *>Почему функция возвращает None в Python&* - потому что не выполнился какой-то if.

Comment: Так вроде должен выполнится?)

Comment: Потому что решил неправильно  Что  должно быть, если b>с?

Comment: А ведь должно получится много if-ов?

Comment: Или я как то не так решаю?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самое короткое решение

```
def maximum(*args):
    return sorted(args)[1:]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = int(input('Введите первое число: '))
b = int(input('Введите второе число: '))
c = int(input('Введите третье число: '))

def maximum(a, b, c):
    l = [a, b, c]
    minimum = 0

    if l[1] < l[minimum]:
        minimum = 1
    if l[2] < l[minimum]:
        minimum = 2

    if minimum == 0:
        return l[1], l[2]
    if minimum == 1:
        return l[0], l[2]
    if minimum == 2:
        return l[0], l[1]

print('Два максимальных элемента: {0}, {1}'.format(*maximum(a, b, c)))
```

Comment: Спасибо, а то сам что то тупил)

Comment: Как-то слишком заморочено.

Comment: @Эникейщик, тут согласен. Однако, учитывая, что это учебная задача, не исключено, что на её решение наложено дополнительное ограничение в виде запрета на стандартные функции. Поэтому и предоставил решение без использования таковых